# Ignore wildcard exceptions in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of exceptions that looks like this that I don't care about for a specific request:

```
ignore_exceptions = (requests.exceptions.MissingSchema,
                     requests.exceptions.SSLError,
                     requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout,
                     requests.exceptions.ConnectionError,
                     requests.exceptions.InvalidURL,
                     ssl.SSLError)
```

Is there a way to do something like this...

```
    ignore_exceptions = (requests.exceptions.*,
                         ssl.SSLError)
```

If I don't care about of those exceptions? I could just do "except:" since I don't really care about any of these calls but I figured I'd ask (plus I hear it makes Guido van Rossum spin in his grave).

Comment: Only if they are all derived from some common base class that you can catch instead of each one individually.  Otherwise, no, not really.

Comment: Guido is alive dude.

Comment: It's preemptive spinning. Ignoring requests.exceptions doesn't seem to do the trick, would I have to ignore all the exceptions that are children of a common parent exception by ignoring the parent?

Comment: `except requests.exceptions.RequestException`, http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#errors-and-exceptions

Comment: You should put this as an answer as it's better than the one I chose (or more specific anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Not a great idea. But if you want a list of all the callables other than

```
ignore_exceptions.extend([getattr(requests.exceptions, x) 
                              for x in dir(requests.exceptions) 
                                          if x.find('__') == -1])
```

Comment: I'd agree it's not a great idea, I ended up biting the bullet and throwing in 'exception:' at the end (generally a bad idea but what fits the bill in this specific circumstance). I'll hold onto the getattr option for the future though.